# How to access Samba on Raspi in Workgroup from my Win10 on Domain

Tags: raspbian-jessie, samba

In my home network, I am running Samba on a Pi and it is running well for a long time. I can access it from my multiple laptops running Windows 10. However, with the addition of the latest win 10 laptop (from my work), I cannot access the Samba share from this laptop. I can still use it from the other laptops. From that angle, I know the Pi is running fine.

**What I have tried:**
I read that SMB1 is disabled in Win 10 by default. I enabled that and tried. Got no success.

On the work laptop, I cannot change most of the group policies. One policy that disables unauthenticated access to shares using SMB2. There is a GPO that can easily be flipped to fix the problem if setting up auth isn't an option. Here is the policy in question.

```
Computer configuration\administrative templates\network\Lanman Workstation "Enable insecure guest logons"
```

I tried this but still got no success. The Samba share needs authentication.

Can someone help?

Comment: Your Win10 Samba problem seems a bit complicated.  So the following simple work around won't help? How to access files on network devices using SMBv1 on Windows 10 - MAURO HUCULAK 23 May 2018:
https://www.windowscentral.com/how-access-files-network-devices-using-smbv1-windows-10. 

If you can no longer access network files, chances are your device is still using the SMB version 1 protocol, which is no longer supported on Windows 10. Here's a workaround to regain access to your files.

Comment: @tlfong01 As I wrote in the post, I have tried enabling SMB1 as in the post you provided the link to. But that does not solve the problem.

Answer (score -1):

***Question***

> How to access Samba on Raspi from my Win10?

***Answer***

> Just now I installed a quick and dirty version on my Rpi4B buster
> following Ref 1.  Then I connected my Win10 to Samba following Ref 2.
>
> Since my Samba server welcomes guests, so I just use my Win10 File
> Explorer to visit the Samba server at
> share(192.168.1.3(Samba4.9.5-Debian))

*/ to continue, ...*

***Notes:***

1. I am using Chinese Window 10.  Last major upgrade is 2018 Aug. I never refuse upgrade suggestions.  Last minor upgrade should be about a week ago.

---

> ***Update 2019sep27hkt2302***

I made a careless mistake of not pointing out the above paragraphs of setting up a quick and dirty Samba is the answer.  Actually it is only the first of perhaps 4 big steps in solving the OP's problem.

My 4 step troubleshooting plan is summarized below:

1. Set up a minimal workable Samba server with NO security at all (777 mode, guest welcome), just to make sure my Rpi4B buster is compatible to the Samba driver.
2. Add group/user passwords, and increase security by stepping down 777 to 775 and lower.
3. Study the OP's problem related to the following policy:

> Computer configuration\administrative templates\network\Lanman
> Workstation "Enable insecure guest logons"

I guess there might be some Win10/Rpi incompatibility here, causing confusion, ...

4. / to continue, ...

/to continue, ...

***References***

(1) [Samba - Set up a Rpi as a file server for your local network](https://www.raspberrypi.org/magpi/samba-file-server/)

(2) [How to connect to Linux Samba shares from Windows 10](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-connect-to-linux-samba-shares-from-windows-10/)

***Appendices***

(A) *Rpi4B buster Installation Notes*

> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get upgrade
>
> sudo apt-get install samba samba-common-bin
>
> sudo mkdir -m 1777 /share
>
> sudo nano /etc/samba/smb.conf
>
> ***[share]***
>
> Comment = Pi shared folder Path = /share
>
> Browseable = yes
>
> Writeable = Yes
>
> only guest = no
>
> create mask = 0777
>
> directory mask = 0777
>
> Public = yes
>
> ***Guest ok = yes***
>
> sudo smbpasswd -a pi tlfong01 tlfong01

*(B) How to start smbd*

> ***sudo systemctl restart smbd***

*(C) Chinese Windows 10 Side Setup Notes*

> SambaNetwork Address
>
> My Computer >
>
> ***share(192.168.1.3(Samba4.9.5-Debian))***

Comment: Wish you could spend little time reading through the OP completely. You could have saved some time for yourself and me as well.

Comment: @Kangkan, My apologies for wrongly interpreting your question.  Let me read your question again and see if I should make a bigger apology.

Comment: I made a quick read of the question.  I think I understand the big picture.  I must confess I don't know the following: (1) difference between SMB1 and SMB2, (2) Group policies.  I have been using Pure-FTPd where I use group policies etc.  For SMB, I deliberately set up the simplest no security version (777 mode, guest welcome), then I will tighten up security, by setting up user and group policies etc. I am glad that you stratightforwardly pointing out that I am not directly and quickly answer your point up to the point, reproducing exactly your situation and pin point the critical, ...

Comment: I must admit that my ftp/http/smba experience is at user level, though I set up and maintain my own home network for years.  I am offering help because I know there are not too many Rpi4B/buster/samba hobbyist around, therefore my newbie experience might still hopefully brainstorm professionals.  Another reason for answering is that my newbie experience might be helpful to future newbies setting up Samba/ftp/NAS servers.  Now I know I made a mistake.  My apologies again for wasting your time. Cheers.